# Dynamic name string editorfor ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, sql-server-2017, editorfor

Model:

```
public class abc
{
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public long? p1 { get; set; }
    public long pa1 { get; set; }
    public long? bv1 { get; set; }
    public string ad1 { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
List<object> value_model = new List<object>();

value_model.Add(new value_model{ namemodel= "ad1", display= "display addd"});
value_model.Add(new value_model{ namemodel= "pa1", display= "display pa1 "});`

@foreach (var item in collection)
{
    <label>item.display</label>
    @Html.EditorFor(m =>item.namemodel)
}
```

I want to pass the value of model name and will get back to EditorFor as I want. But I can't do it. Hope to work.

Comment: you are adding `namemodel` in `value_model` and trying to access it from `collection`, it does not make any sense.

Comment: That's how I describe the direction to do it. The direction I'm going to is @ Html.EditorFor (m => m.GetType (). GetProperties ("item.namemodel")).

Comment: ok, so `value_model` is the model hat you are passing from controller, right?

Comment: yes, I would like to take the data of ad1 and pa1 as declared and EditorFor will understand the data type from the model.

Comment: then you have to add  property in class  namely `namemodel` and `display`

Comment: Can you demo 1 line of code to get the value of dynamic name string for me?

Comment: your viewmodel will be come from the controller and all property inside viewmodel class should be pre defined